# Windows 11: a special requirement on the HW?

Tags: windows-11, desktop-computer, tpm

Is there some special requirement when I want to install and use Windows 11 on my PC ?
May I delete my Windows 8.1 and simply buy a CD-ROM with 11 and in fact change no component, be it processor or MB or some special component ? There are contradictory answers on Internet to this question.

Comment: Any machine that came with Windows 8.1 installed on it would official NOT meet the system requirements of Windows 11.  That does not mean Windows 11 won't run on those machines.  It does mean you will have to use the current method to force Windows 11 to install on incompatible machines. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Also I doubt the bios will support 10 or 11.

Comment: The older machine I referenced supported (supports) Windows 10 just fine. That should likely work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there special requirements?  Yes.

You need TPM V2, UEFI and Secure Boot. The CPU needs to be generation 8 or better (so about 4 years old or newer at this point).

A Windows 8.1 PC will have a CPU that is too old to run Windows 11, so what you want to do won't work for Windows 11 Production.
.

What you can do is join the Windows Insider Program and attempt to put Windows 11 on the computer that way. Windows Insider and the known flags to skirt around the requirements do the same thing. But you need to be aware of the limitations.

This may work (I have one running this way) or may not work (just too old). I have an older machine that I am returning to Windows 10 because the newest versions of Windows 11 will not run it.

You might be better off to upgrade your machine to Windows 10. That will most likely work.

I have two Windows 11 Pro Production machines so I have the range of machines for what you are trying to do.

Comment: There's also scripts that disable checks at install time but naturally, it's something to do at your own risk.